# Filesystem permissions for /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/.MSIC/Incoming

Tags: ios, jailbreak, filesystem

I have changed the permissions on `/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/.MSIC/Incoming`. Now my camera cannot take pictures. Maybe picture is taken but it cannot write it. I want to fix the permissions issue. Could somebody tell me what the permissions should be (iPhone 5s iOS 8.1)?

Comment: Try sudo chmod -R 770 directory/goes/here

Answer (score 1):

The permissions on directories in `/var/mobile` are `drwxr-xr-x` (`755`).